# Java Library's Parameter Name differs between projects

Tags: java, maven, spring-security, parameters, pom.xml

I am developing Web Services with the following stacks:

1. Spring Boot with Spring Security
2. Maven -> add dependency from Maven Repo on pom.xml
3. Vs Code
4. Two Project (Two VS Code Windows): Production Development & Testing
5. List item

Desc:

- In using 'SessionRegistry', when I try to see what is inside the 'SessionRegistry.class', the name of the parameters are as the image below:

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbRxK.png)
Image_1.1) shows no indication on the purpose of the parameter as encircled on the image on the production project.

Stats on Testing Project, and this is my actual Expectation:

[Expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is2Wb.png) Image_1.2) has appropriate name of the parameter and it shows sense what is the purpose of the parameter.

++ Both of the Project is referring the same dependency thru pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

What I have already tried:

1. I have even tried to remove and download all of the dependencies at the Users/../.m2/repository
2. Wondered if the outdated version was the cause... so even tried to indicate the latest version enumerated on official maven repository website with the follwoing version:

--

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Awaiting for your advise with an advance grafulness.

Comment: The issue within an IDE is that you usally don't have the source code available. But most IDE have an option to download the appropriate source code... I bet VS Code has also such kind of option...this must be configured otherwise your IDE will use a decompiler to show the code which obviously is not really readable...

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Ill look into it along with your advise.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided the source code for the library. Without the source, the IDE will still show the prototype (since that can be determined from the .class file) but it will make up names for the arguments, as you see.

Refer to the VSCode documentation to learn how to attach source jars.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Source Code of the Library as it is shown when I open up the file with my IDE is as just like the images that I included on the post. And both of the images are all .class files in different project